# Nested Generic Type Inference in f#

Tags: f#

In the following code I define two interfaces, the second of which takes the first as a type parameter. However the code gives the error "type parameter 'a' is not defined".

```
type IFirst<'a> = 
    abstract Data : 'a

type ISecond<'First when 'First :> IFirst<'a>> = 
    abstract First : 'First
    abstract SomeData : 'a
```

My question is why can't f# infer what type 'a' is when ISecond is derived, since the information is embedded in 'First'?
For example in the following code the compiler could infer that 'a' is a string.

```
type First () =
    interface IFirst<string> with
        member x.Data = ""

type Second () =
    interface ISecond<First> with
        member x.SomeData = ""
        member x.First = First()
```

Is there any way around this or does ISecond have to take two type parameters?

**EDIT:** I Am aware that ISecond can take two type parameters (note the last line of my initial question). To make it clearer what I mean consider the following code

```
type IFirst<'a> = interface end

type ISecond<'First, 'a when 'First :> IFirst<'a>> = interface end

type First () =
    interface IFirst<string> 

type Second () =
    interface ISecond<First, int>
```

It gives the error "This expression was expected to have type string but here has type int", meaning the compiler knows that 'a' is a string, yet I still have to declare it as such. I wish to know why this is the case and whether there is a workaround without specifying the second type parameter.

Comment: You need to add the second parameter - `'a` is not in scope otherwise (it's not really about inference, it's about the structure of types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have conflated two different questions.  One is:

> Do a type definition's generic parameters all need to be explicit?

The answer is yes.  This has nothing to do with type inference, it's just how type definitions work in F# - the type parameter `'a` will only be in scope to be used as an argument to `IFirst<_>` if it's also a parameter of `ISecond`.

The other question is:

> Can the compiler infer a super-type's type parameters when defining a subtype?

Here, the answer is slightly more subtle.  When defining a class type, the answer is that it is a syntactic requirement that you specify all of the type parameters.  If you try something like:

```
type Second() = interface ISecond<First,_> with ...
```

you'll get the error message

```
error FS0715: Anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration
```

However, there are other contexts where the parameters can be inferred without issue:

```
let second() = { new ISecond<_,_> with
                    member x.SomeData = ""
                    member x.First = First() }
```

Here you can see that when using an object expression both of the parameters can be inferred.

Comment: Nice, your solution was just what I was looking for. Is there a specific reason anonymous types can't be used in type declarations?

Comment: @AmirVakili - That's a good question, but unfortunately I don't know the answer.  If the parameters are underconstrained, then in the case of an object expression the result can be generic but that wouldn't make sense in a type definition (so you'd need to raise an error in that particular case).  But more generally, if a feature is missing the answer to _why_ is often "no one ever implemented it" rather than that there was some specific blocker.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks for all the help ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of `ISecond` is incorrect: you're mentioning some type `'a`, but not defining it. In other words, `ISecond` actually has *two* generic parameters - `'First` and `'a`, but you've only defined one of them.

This would work:

```
type ISecond<'a, 'First when 'First :> IFirst<'a>> = 
    abstract First : 'First
    abstract SomeData : 'a
```

But then, of course, you'll need to amend your definition of `Second` as well:

```
type Second () =
    interface ISecond<string, First> with
        member x.SomeData = ""
        member x.First = First()
```